# How to type an HOC correctly in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm getting an error about props missing in type if i try to use a prop passed down from an HOC.

I've tried multiple things but after some research i came up with the following code that seems quite correct to me, logically speaking, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

This is my solution:

```
interface INavigationContext {
  componentId?: string;
}

interface IAddNavigationContextProps {
  navigation: INavigationContext;
}

export function addNavigationContext<P extends object >(
  Component: React.ComponentType<P>,
): React.ComponentType<P & IAddNavigationContextProps> {
  const WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P & IAddNavigationContextProps> = (props: P) => (
    <NavigationContext.Consumer>
      {(navigationState: INavigationContext) => (
        <Component {...props as P} navigation={navigationState} />
      )}
    </NavigationContext.Consumer>
  );

  WrappedComponent.displayName = `addNavigationContext(${getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)})`;

  return WrappedComponent;
}
```

This is the error i get:

```
Property 'navigation' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
```

I expect that if wrap a component like this:
`addNavigationContext(MyComponent)`

then i get no type errors if i use `this.props.navigation` inside `MyComponent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your HOC needs to receive a component which expects its own `Props` and `IAddNavigationContextProps`

```
Component: React.ComponentType<P & IAddNavigationContextProps>
```

Secondly, your HOC needs to return a component which expects only its own `Props`

```
React.ComponentType<P>
```

Put together

```
export function addNavigationContext<P = {}>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<P & IAddNavigationContextProps>,
): React.ComponentType<P> {
    const WrappedComponent: React.FC<P> = props => (
        <NavigationContext.Consumer>
            {(navigationState: INavigationContext) => <Component {...props} navigation={navigationState} />}
        </NavigationContext.Consumer>
    );

    WrappedComponent.displayName = `addNavigationContext(${getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)})`;

    return WrappedComponent;
}

const MyComponent = addNavigationContext(({ children, navigation }) => <p>Magic</p>);
```

Comment: so this means that i've to anyway declare navigation prop in `MyComponent` interface, do I?

because i've like `class MyComponent extends Component<IProps> {}` `addNavigationContext(MyComponent)` i thought it would be possible to avoid `navigation` type on every component that use the HOC if the HOC was typed correctly.

Comment: @StefanoCerelli If you don't want to specify it in the interface, you need to write it inline, as i did at the bottom of my example.